# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized in .NET 8 with EF Core 8 and SQL Server 2022

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, connection-string

I am working on a .NET 8 application using Entity Framework Core 8 and targeting SQL Server 2022 (Express Edition). Despite having a correct connection string in my appsettings.json, I am encountering an InvalidOperationException stating that the ConnectionString property has not been initialized. The error occurs when I try to run Update-Database in the Package Manager Console.

Here's the error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
[...stack trace...]
```

The relevant part of my appsettings.json looks like this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnexion": "Server=DESKTOP-39TI737\\sqlexpress;Database=Mango_Coupon;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"
}
```

And in my Program.cs (as I'm using .NET 8), the DbContext is configured like this:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnexion")); 
});
```

I have verified that the SQL Server is running and accessible via SSMS. The issue seems to be specific to the application's attempt to access the database.

Any insights into what might be causing this issue or how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

1. I verified that the connection string is correctly named as "DefaultConnexion" and the format is correct.
2. Reviewed DbContext Configuration
3. I confirmed that the SQL Server instance is running and is accessible via SSMS
4. I executed Update-Database with -Verbose to get more detailed information about the error

Comment: Have you selected the project with settings as the start up one in the VS solution explorer?

Comment: Try explicitly setting the connection string in the `AddDbContext` method without using the `GetConnectionString` method, just to see if that resolves the issue or not.

Comment: @AmitMohanty
I tried explicitly setting the connection string directly in the AddDbContext method, by passing the GetConnectionString method, and it worked!  
I'm curious about the underlying reason why this approach worked, whereas using GetConnectionString did not. Is there a potential issue or limitation with GetConnectionString method or the way configuration is handled in .NET 8 that I should be aware of?

Comment: Sometimes, during the application's startup, the configuration might not have been loaded at the point when `AddDbContext` is called. So verify that the configuration is loaded before the `AddDbContext` call during the application startup.

Comment: This issue may caused by you cannot get the connection string. Pls debug your code and check if `builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnexion")` contains value or not. Also be sure the connection string exists in the apppsettings.json instead of any other json file.